# Is there SD card to CF card adapter that supports SD 4.0 (UHS-II)?

Tags: memory-card, sdcard, cfcard, sdxc

I have a micro SD card and a normal SD card which runs on the SD 4.0 specification, allowing high data transfer speeds. I also have a 5D Mark IV, which unfortunately only supports the UHS-I protocol in its SD card slot. It has a CF card that can support much higher data transfer speeds (allowing for better bust mode photo saving), but it is not compatible with my SD/micro SD cards.

Is there any sort of CF to SD or CF to micro-SD adapter which supports SD 4.0 speeds?

[Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EPMWT1M) is a link to an adapter on Amazon. It only supports UHS-I/SD 3.0 and doesn't supports cards over 32GB. My cards are 64GB or 128GB.

[Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074S7XX97) is another one that only supports SD 3.0.

The others I've seen only supports SD 3.0 speeds as well.